# What is the recommended alternative to DisplayFormatAttribute in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

So I found the `DisplayFormatAttribute` class (I guess that is for Web development only?).  It would really improve my project in terms of maintainability, as I have a number of decimal properties whose number of decimal places seem to change again and again (customer requirements mixed with my "clever" ideas).

Basically, I would have a property like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n4} %")]
public decimal Nh3 {get; set;}
```

which, as the `DisplayFormatAttribute` indicates, needs to be displayed with four decimals in the current users locale followed by a %.

In XAML I would have something like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Nh3}"/>
```

But for a value like `0.123456` it will display `0.123456` and for a value like `0.12` it will display `0.12`.  I need it to display `0.1235 %` and `0.1200 %` respectively.

This can be achieved for the particular `TextBlock` via

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Nh3, StringFormat={}{0:n4} %"/>
```

but that is, as I mentioned, repetitive and error-prone.

I've seen someone using something like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Nh3, StringFormat={StaticResource Nh3Format} %"/>
```

but I find that rather convoluted (compared to an attribute on the `Nh3` property).  But I hope someone can help me solve this in a better way.

Comment: You could create a value converter (see https://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html how to create and use one) which takes the binding value and calls "var formatString = value.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<DisplayFormatAttribute>()?.DataFormatString" to extract the formatting, applies it to value per "string.Format(formatString, value)" and returns this string, which then gets automatically bound to your controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own `DisplayFormatAttribute` and a [custom markup-extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml) to automatically create these binding(s) for you.

```
///Custom attribute
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DisplayFormatAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string DataFormatString { get; set; }
}

///Custom markup extension
[ContentProperty("ResourceKey")]
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class FormattedBindingExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public FormattedBindingExtension()
    {
    }

    public FormattedBindingExtension(PropertyPath path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }
    public object ConverterParamter { get; set; }

    [ConstructorArgument("path")]
    public PropertyPath Path { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(CultureInfoIetfLanguageTagConverter))]
    public CultureInfo ConverterCulture { get; set; }

    private DependencyProperty _bindingTargetProperty;
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var valueProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
        if (valueProvider != null)
        {
            var bindingTarget = valueProvider.TargetObject as DependencyObject;
            var bindingTargetProperty = valueProvider.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
            if (bindingTargetProperty == null || bindingTarget == null || Path == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format(
                    "The property '{0}' on target '{1}' is not valid for a FormattedBinding. The FormattedBinding target must be a DependencyObject, "
                    + "and the target property must be a DependencyProperty, and a Path must be specified.",
                    valueProvider.TargetProperty,
                    valueProvider.TargetObject));
            }

            // Add support so that the datacontext change causes an immediate commit with format
            var frameworkElement = bindingTarget as FrameworkElement;
            if (frameworkElement != null)
            {
                frameworkElement.DataContextChanged += FrameworkElement_DataContextChanged;
            }

            _bindingTargetProperty = bindingTargetProperty;
            FrameworkElement_DataContextChanged(frameworkElement, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs());

            // Return the current value of the binding (since it will have been evaluated because of the binding above)
            return bindingTarget.GetValue(bindingTargetProperty);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void FrameworkElement_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs ignored)
    {
        var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null || element.DataContext == null)
            return;

        var propertyName = Path.Path;
        if (propertyName == null)
            return;

        var source = element.DataContext;
        var type = source.GetType();

        var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        var format = property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayFormatAttribute>()?.DataFormatString;
        Binding binding = GetBinding(format);

        // Apply and evaluate the binding
        var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, _bindingTargetProperty, binding);
        bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();
    }

    private Binding GetBinding(string format)
    {
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = Path;
        binding.Converter = Converter;
        binding.ConverterCulture = ConverterCulture;
        binding.ConverterParameter = ConverterParamter;
        binding.StringFormat = format;
        return binding;
    }
}
```

### Sample usage:

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Text="{local:FormattedBinding Path=Nh3}"  />

<!-- specify price US currency -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:FormattedBinding Path=Price, ConverterCulture='en-US'}" />

<!-- specify price German currency -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:FormattedBinding Path=Price, ConverterCulture='de-DE'}" />

<!-- specify price Japanese currency -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:FormattedBinding Path=Price, ConverterCulture='ja-JP'}" />

<TextBlock Text="{local:FormattedBinding Path=Today}" />
```

**ViewModel properties**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n4} %")]
public double Nh3 { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dddd, MMMM dd}")]
public DateTime Today { get; set; }
```

[image]

Comment: This code works fine with the existing DisplayFormatAttribute.  My tests reveal that paths that are not exactly one property name are not supported, but that was easy to correct on top of this.  This is awesome!